# How to query all system under SystemTypes in SQL database in a json format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I have a SQL table like below

| GroupID | CountryName | CityName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | Nellore |
| 1 | India | Chittoor |
| 1 | SriLanka | Kadapa |
| 2 | China | Beijing |
| 2 | China | Vwk |

i want to output as json format as below

```
[
  {
    "GroupId": 1,
    "Data": [
      {
        "Country" : "India",
        "City" : ["India" || "Nellore"] 
      },
      {
        "Country" : "SriLanka",
        "City" : ["Kadapa"] 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "GroupId": 2,
    "Data": [
      {
        "Country" : "China",
        "City" : ["Beijing" || "Vwk"] 
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I tried to achieve this by different queries but didn't get it

Could some one help me with this query

Comment: That's not valid JSON, the array elements should be separated by `,` and no trailing `,` at the end of objects. What does [tag:java] or [tag:c#] have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation here, plus a final `FOR JSON`.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `JSON_AGG` or `JSON_OBJECT_AGG` which would have made this easier. You need to hack it with a combination of `STRING_ESCAPE` and `STRING_AGG`, as well as `JSON_QUERY` to prevent double-escaping.

```sql
WITH ByCountry AS (
    SELECT
      t.GroupId,
      t.CountryName,
      City = '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(t.CityName, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.GroupId,
      t.CountryName
)
SELECT
  c.GroupId,
  Data = JSON_QUERY('[' + STRING_AGG(j.json, ',') + ']')
FROM ByCountry c
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    c.GroupId,
    c.CountryName,
    City = JSON_QUERY(c.City)
  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) j(json)
GROUP BY
  c.GroupId
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/1wPSuu6B)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more table called GroupName where i have a columns like GroupId, GroupName. so in the output I need { GroupId : "1",GroupName: "ECE", Data: [] } . where can we use join condition to join GroupName table

Comment: Instead of `FROM YourTable t` do `FROM table1 JOIN table2` etc. A [mcve] would have been useful. If you have any further problems I suggest yo create a *new* question for that

Comment: I'm unable to add this doubt as new question, so could you please say like what is "j(json)" and "j.josn" we used in the query ?

Comment: `j(json)` is an alias for the subquery: `j` is the name of the table and `json` is the single column that results from the `FOR JSON` clause. That's why you can then refer to it like any other table `j.json`